# I want to optimize a parameter string

Tags: optimization, ant

I have this

```
<path id="bootclasspath">
        <pathelement path="${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/cldcapi10.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/cldcapi11.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi10.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi20.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi21.jar"/>
</path>
```

witch i need somewere and also somwhere i have this:

```
<arg line="-classpath ${dir.classes};${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/cldcapi10.jar;${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/cldcapi11.jar;{J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi10.jar;${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi20.jar;${J2MEWTK.HOME}/lib/midpapi21.jar -d ${dir.classes} ${dir.classes} "/>
```

It works, it's ok, but the question is: how can I write the argument string to be generated from the path element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [`pathconvert` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html), something like:

```
<pathconvert refid="bootclasspath" property="bootcp" pathsep=";"/>
...
<arg line="-classpath ${dir.classes};${bootcp} -d ${dir.classes} ${dir.classes} "/>
```